# What options are there for collaborating with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: web, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare, codespaces

Me and my friend are planning on doing html/css/javascript development, and I was looking at Visual Studio Code as an option for working on this together. We live in seperate areas, and of course COVID-19 as well is here, so we need to do this remotely. I've seen that Visual Studio Code has Live Share, but that's not something that would work, as it requires the host be online to edit the code. Next, I found out about "Codespaces", and it seems to be good, but it would turn out to be quite expensive for us ($20-$30 a month), as we're still high school students. Then I thought of the idea to use GitHub with it, and just store it locally on my friend and I's PCs, and just do commits and pull requests on there and bring it in to our local machines.

So My Question: What options are there for remote collaboration with Microsoft Visual Studio Code?

Comment: You don't need GitHub to pull and push too, set the computer of your friend as the remote and push/pull from that remote. no need to do pull requests. Or do it like Linus does it before git, exchange tar ball diffs

Comment: Do you plan to modify VSC: I was looking at Visual Studio Code as an option for working **on this** together. Or do you mean **using this**? You are just programming for a month, then VSC is not a project to start working on but with.

Comment: How would that be set up? I'm quite unfamiliar with how exactly git and GitHub work, though I do know that GitHub is just a cloud platform to make Git easier to work with.

Comment: And, would the PC that is the remote have to be online when the other person is trying to do something to the code? Oh also, I meant working **with** visual studio code to develop applications, not on.

Comment: the other PC has to be on, no need to be editing in VSC. The other person is doing something to the repository. VSC has nothing to do with git. Maybe you have to run some kind of daemon to process the git: protocol requests. Have a look in the docs. That is the distributed thing of git, you can push/pull to any repository that has the same "root". There is no need for Github, that is just a copy of the repository that is always available.

Comment: Oh I see. Though I'm not sure that work work for us. I'm looking for a way for my friend and I to both be able to edit the code independently of each other being online. Like some sort of cloud solution to store the code. I thought that GitHub is able to store the code in a repository without one of us being online, thus we'd be able to edit the code at any time. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: It depends if you want your code to be open source. If that is OK you can use GitHub. If you don't want to pay for a private repository on GitHub you can push and pull to each other repository. Only when you push/pull the other computer has to be on(line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping up this question due to its age. We've stuck with VSCode and using GitHub repositories and simply pushing, pulling, doing regular commits.